# C# Active Directory Extended User Principals - proxyAddresses attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am wondering if anyone can help with this one.

I have an extended ad user principals class as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb384372(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. Attributes such as title, pager, postalCode all work wonderfully, but I cannot get proxyAddresses to set - the server just returns the helpful message of "The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid".

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("User")]
public class InetOrgPerson : UserPrincipal
{
    // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public InetOrgPerson(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public InetOrgPerson(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled)
                         : base(context,
                                samAccountName,
                                password,
                                enabled)
    {
    }

    InetOrgPersonSearchFilter searchFilter;

    new public InetOrgPersonSearchFilter AdvancedSearchFilter
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == searchFilter)
                searchFilter = new InetOrgPersonSearchFilter(this);

            return searchFilter;
        }
    }

    // Create the other proxyAddresses property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("proxyAddresses")]
    public string[] ProxyAddresses
    {
        get
        {
            int len = ExtensionGet("proxyAddresses").Length;

            string[] otherHomePhone = new string[len];
            object[] otherHomePhoneRaw = ExtensionGet("proxyAddresses");

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                otherHomePhone[i] = (string)otherHomePhoneRaw[i];
            }

            return otherHomePhone;
        }

        set
        {
            ExtensionSet("proxyAddresses", value);
        }
    }

    // Create the logoncount property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("LogonCount")]
    public Nullable<int> LogonCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("LogonCount").Length != 1)
                return null;

            return ((Nullable<int>)ExtensionGet("LogonCount")[0]);
        }
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity.
    public static new InetOrgPerson FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context,
                                                   string identityValue)
    {
        return (InetOrgPerson)FindByIdentityWithType(context,
                                                     typeof(InetOrgPerson),
                                                     identityValue);
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
    public static new InetOrgPerson FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context,
                                                   IdentityType identityType,
                                                   string identityValue)
    {
        return (InetOrgPerson)FindByIdentityWithType(context,
                                                     typeof(InetOrgPerson),
                                                     identityType,
                                                     identityValue);
    }



}

public class InetOrgPersonSearchFilter : AdvancedFilters
{
    public InetOrgPersonSearchFilter(Principal p) : base(p) { }
    public void LogonCount(int value, MatchType mt)
    {
        this.AdvancedFilterSet("LogonCount", value, typeof(int), mt);
    }

}}
```

And it's called exactly as per the Microsoft tutorial.

```
string[] pa = new string[3];
pa[0] = "SMTP:test@domain.com";
pa[1] = "smtp:test@domaintwo.com";
pa[2] = "smtp:test@domainthree.com";
up.ProxyAddresses = pa;
up.Save();
```

I have also tried to write the same data to the otherHomePhone attribute exactly per the article and I get the same error. I am confused!

Suggestions will be most welcomed.